# Is there a way to disable portrait/login picture display in the Xubuntu login?

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, login-screen

I recently upgraded a machine from XUbuntu 12.10 and now the login screen has a blank silhouette that looks like the Facebook empty profile picture. How do I disable this and get back to just username and password fields at login? (I like the rest of lightdm so I would like to stick with it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in current version (greeter always display icon - user avatar, icon configured in .conf or default).
You can write feature-request if you think that such option is necessary:
https://launchpad.net/lightdm-gtk-greeter

Comment: Do feature requests also go under bug reports?

Comment: Yes, use bug tracker.